# How to build an specific atlas for the $n$-disk $D^n$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

How can we build a topological atlas for the $n$-dimensional disk $D^n=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \lVert x \rVert  \leqslant 1 \}$ as a manifold with boundary ? Specifically, how to construct the maps of charts that cover boundary points ?

Thanks in advance !!
Greetings.

Comment: The closed $n$-disk is not a topological manifold in the usual sense, it is a ["manifold with boundary"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary). Does that clear up or issue, or do you want explicit charts knowing that it's a manifold with boundary?

Comment: yes, i want an explicit atlas of $D^n$ as a manifold with boundary

Comment: you can cover all the points not on the boundary in a single chart. then you can pick two charts, one not containing $1$ and one not containing $-1$ to cover the rest of the points. can you see how to make this explicit?

Comment: Actually, that is the part in which i cannot make some advance, in getting an analytic expression of a map, taking an open set $U\subset D^n$ (such that $U \cap \partial D^n$ is not empty) onto an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n_+$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to pick a point $p\in\partial D^n$ and perform the inversion in unit sphere centered at $p$: namely, $$x\mapsto p+\frac{x-p}{\|x-p\|^2} \tag1$$
This maps $D^n\setminus\{p\}$ onto a half-space. Then do the same with another boundary point, and you have $D^n$ covered.

The usual choice is $p=(0,\dots,0,\pm 1)$, which is very much related to [stereographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection).